# Limit evaluation method clarification $1+\frac{1}{2}+\cdots+\frac{1}{n}=\gamma+\mathcal{E}_n+ln(n)$

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, limits

I came across this limit evaluation method in my notebook, which is very poorly explained.

$$1+\frac{1}{2}+\cdots+\frac{1}{n}=\gamma+\mathcal{E}_n+ln(n)\space,\ \mathcal{E}_n\longrightarrow 0\space\ when\space\ n\longrightarrow\infty$$

Its application on one problem is the following

$$\text{Problem:}\space \lim_{n\to\infty} \frac{1}{n+1}+\frac{1}{n+2}+\cdots+\frac{1}{2n}$$

$$\text{Solution:}\space\frac{1}{n+1}+\frac{1}{n+2}+\cdots+\frac{1}{2n}=\color{navy}{1+\frac{1}{2}+\cdots+\frac{1}{n}+\frac{1}{n+1}+\frac{1}{n+2}\cdots+\frac{1}{2n}-\left(1+\frac{1}{2}+\cdots+\frac{1}{n}\right)}=\gamma+\mathcal{E}_{2n}+ln(2n)-(\gamma+\mathcal{E}_n+ln(n))=\mathcal{E}_{2n}-\mathcal{E}_n+ln(2)$$

$$\text {And thereby,}$$

$$\lim_{n\to\infty} \frac{1}{n+1}+\frac{1}{n+2}+\cdots+\frac{1}{2n}=\lim_{n\to\infty}\underbrace{\mathcal{E}_{2n}}_{\rightarrow 0}-\underbrace{\mathcal{E}_n}_{\rightarrow 0}+ln(2)=ln(2)$$

Alright, I see that the sequence is being manipulated in order to substitute it with the upward formula. What I fail to grasp is the navy highlighted step. 
The other thing I don't understand is the formula and what does it represent, why does it work at all.

Could someone elaborate on what is happening here ?

The formula is introduced in my Analysis course before the derivatives, integrals etc..

Thanks

Comment: The difference step is pretty straightforward, reduce the first n terms of the harmonic sum and you are left with the required sum. About $\gamma$ (Euler-Mascheroni) constant, you should read https://brilliant.org/wiki/euler-mascheroni-constant/

Comment: The highlighted step is: sum from $1$ to $\frac{1}{2n}$ is the sum from $\frac{1}{n+1}$ to $\frac{1}{2n}$ plus the sum from $1$ to $\frac{1}{n}$

Comment: @Atticus I see it now. I read the article. Thanks for the clarification! What is $\mathcal {E}_n$ supposed to be in this case ? Is it maybe the epsilon neighborhood from the limit of a sequence definition ?

Comment: $\mathcal{E}_n$ is just a very small positive term (which is about $\frac{1}{2n}$) and can be negliged for large $n$ (as they do in the proof when it takes the limit $n\to \infty$)

Comment: @Atticus Alright, but wherefrom is the equation coming? I was thinking maybe it was derived from the $$\gamma=\lim_{n \to \infty}1+\frac{1}{2}+\cdots+\frac{1}{n}-ln(n) \space \implies |1+\frac{1}{2}+\cdots+\frac{1}{n}-ln(n)-\gamma|< \epsilon \space \iff 1+\frac{1}{2}+\cdots+\frac{1}{n}<\gamma+\epsilon+ln(n)$$. And that $\mathcal {E}_n$ is some $\epsilon$ which will eventually become $0$ for some $n$ big enough.

Comment: @GrigoriPerelman, you are correct. $H_{n}-\ln n$ is a strictly decreasing sequence, so your $\epsilon$ will become very small for large $n$.

Comment: @Atticus but I was just thinking, I formed an inequality from the definition where the RHS is strictly larger than LHS but in my question it actually says they are **equal**. What happens then that makes them equal ?

Comment: @GrigoriPerelman, It's just that $H_n - \ln n$ is a strictly decreasing sequence that converges toward $\gamma$. So we can say that $H_n-\ln n = \gamma + \mathcal{E}_n$, where $\mathcal{E}_n$ gets smaller every time $n$ increases.

Comment: @Atticus Got it! Thanks a lot man.

Comment: @Atticus I posted a problem solution using this equation asking for verification, you can check it out if you are interested. regards